# Why In JS -> {} + {} gives [Object object] [ Object object]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I am new to JS and I'd like to know why I am facing this situation.
Let's assume we have something like this :

```
var ids = [10,20,30];
var types= ['PIZZA','HAMBURGER','AVOCADO'];
var payload=[];

for(let i = 0; i <= ids.length; i++){
    var id= ids[i];
    var type= types[i];
    var couple= {"id":id ,"type":type};
    console.log(couple);
    payload.push(couple);}
           
console.log('result is ' + payload);
```

**result is :
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]**

I was expecting something like :

```
{ "id" : 10, "type" : "PIZZA" },
{ "id" : 20, "type" : "HAMBURGER" },
{ "id" : 30, "type" : "AVOCADO" }
```

Do you know why
{} + {} gives "[Object object][Object object]" ?
can you please explain to me how can I avoid this in JS?

Thank you as always for your time, waiting for some cool feedback!
have a great day!

Comment: JavaScript converts the object to a string because you're concatenating it to a string, when that happens you get `[Object object]`. The issue is with how you're logging your payload, instead use: `console.log('result is', payload);` to avoid converting the `payload` array to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Js being weakly typed, string + object will convert the object to a string. What you want to do is `console.log('the resulst is',payload)

```js
var ids = [10,20,30];
var types= ['PIZZA','HAMBURGER','AVOCADO'];
var payload=[];

for(let i = 0; i <= ids.length; i++){
    var id= ids[i];
    var type= types[i];
    var couple= {"id":id ,"type":type};
    payload.push(couple);}
           
console.log('result is ', payload);
console.log('object to string', payload.toString())
```